# How can I get rid of additional files to commit after creating a virtual environment in VS Code?

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code

I have cloned a repository from GitHub onto VS Code. I create a virtual environment using

```
python -m venv myenv
```

However the moment I do this, I get thousands of files in my source control tab, which I don't want to commit (pictured below). Am I setting up my virtual environment incorrectly? Or is there a way of getting rid of these files from here?

One solution I've read [here](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/vs-code-has-5000-files-that-need-to-be-commit/250686/12) includes setting up a .gitignore file and writing "node_modules" within it but this doesn't do anything for me. Another was to delete the .git file, this is already in my "files excluded".

[image: Over 1,000 files to commit after virtual environment creation]

Comment: Did you try ignoring the directory in your `.gitignore` ... `myenv/`? You probably do not have the directory named `node_modules/` which is why nothing is ignored.

Comment: "One solution I've read here includes setting up a .gitignore file and writing "node_modules" you're not going to get very far blindly copy/pasting data without understanding context; you have to put the *right* thing into `.gitignore`.    `node_modules` is a node thing, you're in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `/myenv/` in your .gitignore (or whatever the name of your venv directory is). [See also the .gitignore docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). The leading slash anchors relative to the .gitignore file, and the trailing one limits the pattern to apply to directories. If you don't see any changes in the Source Control view immediately after that change, make sure you saved the changes and try pressing the refresh button in the Source Control view.